# "Already up to date" even when the repo is empty

Tags: git

I have two branches , master and development ( as far as i remember the development was checkouted from master )

I have purged all content of development ( its empty locally and remote too ).

I want to now merge all files from master into development:

```
git checkout master
git fetch
git pull
git checkout development
git fetch
git pull
git merge master
```

But all i get is:

```
Already up to date.
```

Error, i tried to `git reset --hard` both `master` and `development` branches but the error still remains.

How can i fix this? Thanks for help!

Result of `git log --oneline --graph --decorate master development` is:

```
* 56e4fdb (HEAD -> development, origin/development)  purge
*   eb6a6f7 Merge branch 'development' of <url> into development
|\
| * bd3960e Edited config file
| * 8293db6 Edited config file
| * f1d6ac8 merging master
| * 2e41d5a merging master
| * 8ad654e merging master
| * c1a298b merging master
* | a8b761f Edited config file
* | 4426459 Edited config file
* | afb50cc merging master
* | de63abb merging master
* | a62a3ef merging master
* | c4cc98c merging master
* | e34c8f5 (origin/master, master)  master
* | b3be19d Merge branch 'master' of <url>
|\|
| * 158c847 Creating config
| * 7ad8a6c Creating config
| * ca61c69 Init config
| * e84261a Initial commit with default config
* b1f686d  master
* 1f31dd8  master
```

Comment: Merge mechanism doesn't care for the state of your files (*What exactly did you mean by "purged content"?*), it compares commits. It seems to indicate that your `development` branch already has everything that's on `master`. Care to show us the output of `git log --oneline --graph --decorate master development` to confirm it?

Comment: @RomainValeri updated the question of result.

Comment: As you can see, master is already an ancestor of development. Therefore, `git merge` tells you `Already up to date.` There is nothing wrong. It is unclear what you want to fix.

Comment: i added files to master and want to merge them into development.

Comment: @Johnyb In git, one doesn't "add files" to branches. If you didn't add **commits**, you didn't add anything to `master`, you only changed some files on your filesystem.

Comment: i did add push the files into master remote repository.

Comment: Your graph says otherwise, though. But.... oh. Do you actually try to just ditch whatever is currently on development to make it just as it is on master?

Answer (score 0):

@johnyb as you mentioned that you are trying to get the latest files/updates from master into your development branch and  for this please follow the below steps:

1. git stash   --> save your changes(development branch) in temp place
2. git checkout main (or master)
3. git pull
4. git checkout development branch name
5. git reset --hard origin/development branch name
6. git stash pop  --> apply back your changes if any